# Routes with trailing slashes in Pyramid

Tags: python, url-routing, pyramid

Let's say I have a route '/foo/bar/baz'.
I would also like to have another view corresponding to '/foo' or '/foo/'. 
But I don't want to systematically append trailing slashes for other routes, only for /foo and a few others (/buz but not /biz)

From what I saw I cannot simply define two routes with the same route_name. 
I currently do this:

```
config.add_route('foo', '/foo')
config.add_route('foo_slash', '/foo/')
config.add_view(lambda _,__: HTTPFound('/foo'), route_name='foo_slash')
```

Is there something more elegant in Pyramid to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this solution when I was looking for the same thing for my project

```
def add_auto_route(config,name, pattern, **kw):
    config.add_route(name, pattern, **kw)
    if not pattern.endswith('/'):
        config.add_route(name + '_auto', pattern + '/')
        def redirector(request):
            return HTTPMovedPermanently(request.route_url(name))
        config.add_view(redirector, route_name=name + '_auto')
```

And then during route configuration,

```
add_auto_route(config,'events','/events')
```

Rather than doing `config.add_route('events','/events')`

Basically it is a hybrid of your methods. A new route with name ending in `_auto` is defined and its view redirects to the original route.

**EDIT**

The solution does not take into account dynamic URL components and GET parameters. For a URL like `/abc/{def}?m=aasa`, using `add_auto_route()` will throw a key error because the `redirector` function does not take into account `request.matchdict`. The below code does that. To access GET parameters it also uses `_query=request.GET`

```
def add_auto_route(config,name, pattern, **kw):
    config.add_route(name, pattern, **kw)
    if not pattern.endswith('/'):
        config.add_route(name + '_auto', pattern + '/')
        def redirector(request):
            return HTTPMovedPermanently(request.route_url(name,_query=request.GET,**request.matchdict))
        config.add_view(redirector, route_name=name + '_auto')
```

Comment: Nice! For completeness: 'from pyramid.httpexceptions import HTTPMovedPermanently'

Comment: This is nice. However, it does feel "hacky."

Answer (score 11):

Pyramid has a way for `HTTPNotFound` views to **automatically append a slash** and test the routes again for a match (the way Django's `APPEND_SLASH=True` works). Take a look at:

**http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#redirecting-to-slash-appended-routes**

As per this example, you can use `config.add_notfound_view(notfound, append_slash=True)`, where `notfound` is a function that defines your `HTTPNotFound` view. If a view is not found (because it didn't match due to a missing slash), the `HTTPNotFound` view will append a slash and try again. The example shown in the link above is pretty informative, but let me know if you have any additional questions.

Also, heed the warning that this should not be used with POST requests.

There are also many ways to skin a cat in Pyramid, so you can play around and achieve this in different ways too, but you have the concept now.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution. But this will try to append a slash with all not matched routes, and I said in the question that I did not want that.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. I'll leave this response up just for Google though, in case anyone is in fact looking for this method.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. It looks like we can chain two @view_config. So this solution is possible:

```
@view_config(route_name='foo_slash', renderer='myproject:templates/foo.mako')    
@view_config(route_name='foo', renderer='myproject:templates/foo.mako')
def foo(request):
   #do something
```

Its behavior is also different from the question. The solution from the question performs a redirect, so the url changes in the browser. In the second form both /foo and /foo/ can appear in the browser, depending on what the user entered.  I don't really mind, but repeating the renderer path is also awkward.

Comment: But, multiple urls for the same page makes internal tracking/analytics more difficult (or inaccurate). It can also dilute external metrics, whether search page rank or social media popularity. Granted, these may not matter in a particular case, but I think it's a bad habit that's best avoided to minimize the chance it gets used elsewhere.