# How to use bare path (no slash) when including pyramid config?

Tags: python, url-routing, pyramid

I'm attempting to make a modular pyramid application by [including a callable](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#using-a-route-prefix-to-compose-applications) containing several config.add_route functions. In my **init**.py:

```
def devices_include(config):
    config.add_route("devices.collection", "/")
    config.add_route("devices.single", "/{device_id}")
    ...

def main(global_config, **settings):
    ...
    config.include(devices_include, route_prefix="/devices")
```

This code works, meaning when I go to `/devices/` it runs the `devices.collection` function and when I go to `/devices/1` it runs the `devices.single` function. However, I would like to be able to run the `devices.collection` function when going to `/devices` (no trailing slash). How could I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705399/routes-with-trailing-slashes-in-pyramid

Comment: @StevePiercy I'd argue that this is not a duplicate. This is specifically about the route prefixing and being able to call the bare `/routeprefix` rather than `/routeprefix/`

Comment: Did you try the [technique in the first answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15708788/2214933)? I understand the question is dissimilar, but the answer might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to dive into https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/406 and very many linked issues. The short answer is that you'll need to stop using `route_prefix` if you want it to work or you can do some hacky internal url rewriting. It's a feature under discussion for Pyramid 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Currently that is not possible, per Michael Merickel answer.

However there is a workaround:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    ...
    config.include(devices_include, route_prefix="/devices")
    config.add_route('devices.collection', '/devices')
```

Notice the last line.